# Run Javascript Code

Tags: javascript

I need to run javascript in php or python or java. My problem is, when a dynamic page load in browser some javascript executes and add some content on html. But if i download the file using wget or any programming language then i can not find the dynamic portion. I am giving you an example:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <script type="text/javascript" >
         document.body.innerHTML= "hello world";
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

In the above code when i run the code in browser it shows hello world. But if i download the file or open with text editor i will see nothing.  So i need to get the output using any programming language. For that i need to execute the javascript. [python,c/c++,php,javascript,java] any language.

Comment: [Why](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/) do you need the dynamically generated document source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Java has it too.

[Javax Script Engine](http://metoojava.wordpress.com/2010/06/20/execute-javascript-from-java/)

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a [V8 JavaScript Engine Integration inside PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/v8js.examples.php).

I'm not sure whether this is

- stable,
- usable,
- sensible

at all, but at least it seems this could be an approach for solving your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the easiest way to use something like Selenium to control a real browser, then to do it that way.

Trying to parse it otherwise will be a problem, as there may be ajax request etc which will cause issues.